# Finite series with binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

There is a finite series:

\begin{equation}
   \mathscr{S} = \sum_{n=0}^{m} {m \choose n}(m-2n)^2
\end{equation}

If I divide $\mathscr{S}$ by $2^{m}$ I get m. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: You might not feel like adding $2020$ addends together by hand, but that does  not make the series infinite :)

Comment: What have you tried? Of course the first step is to replace $2019$ by $m$. Now, if you expand the square, do you get anything more familiar?

Comment: Sorry, I mean non-infinite series

Comment: I know that $2^{2019}$ is same as $\sum_{n=0}^{2019} {2019 \choose n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Write

$$(m-2n)^2=m^2+an+bn(n-1)$$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants

so that $$\binom mn(m-2n)^2=m^2\binom mn+a n\cdot\binom mn+bn(n-1)\cdot\binom mn$$

Can you find $a,b?$

For $n\ge1,$
$$n\binom mn=\cdots=m\binom{m-1}{n-1}$$

For $n\ge2,$
$$n(n-1)\binom mn=\cdots=m(m-1)\binom{m-2}{n-2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this solution (hint), could you explain it.

Comment: I found that $\sum_{0}^{m} \frac{(m-2n)^2}{2^m- { m \choose n}} = m$

Comment: @TomášMacháček, Please find the updated answer